# How to make sure that at least one element in a collection has a certain value?

Tags: unity, c#

In my game, I assign each agent a random direction. However, at least one of these agents has to have a direction of `Vector2.up`. How can I ensure that?

```
private void AssignRandomDirection()
{
    var directions = new List<Vector2>
    {
        Vector2.up,
        Vector2.down,
        Vector2.left,
        Vector2.right
    };

    foreach (var agent in FindObjectsOfType<Agent>())
    {
        var random = Random.Range(0, directions.Count);
        agent.direction = directions[random];
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you considered checking whether any of the entries is up after random assignment, and if not, choosing one at random to reassign to up? Did you have any trouble making something like this work?

Comment: @DMGregory I don't know how to check if any elements in a list has a certain value.

Comment: ....with the `==` operator? You have the `foreach` already, so you know how to iterate over the items. Can you clarify where you're stuck?

Comment: @DMGregory I know how to use the `foreach` to iterate over the items and check if _all_ of them have a Vector2.up value, but I don't know how to iterate through the list to see if _any_ of them have that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a boolean to keep track of whether you've ever assigned a value of up. If not, inject a value of up at a random position in your collection.

```
private void AssignRandomDirection()
{
    // No need for this to be a list, since you never add/remove elements.
    var directions = new Vector2[]
    {
        Vector2.up,
        Vector2.down,
        Vector2.left,
        Vector2.right
    };

    boolHasAssignedUp = false;

    var agents =  FindObjectsOfType<Agent>();

    foreach (var agent in agents)
    {
        var random = Random.Range(0, directions.Length);
        hasAssignedUp |= (random == 0);
        agent.direction = directions[random];
    }

    if(hasAssignedUp == false)
        agents[Random.Range(0, agents.Length)].direction = directions[0];
}
```

Comment: What does `|=` mean?

Comment: [Did you google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%7C%3D+operator&oq=%7C%3D+operator)? Never underestimate your ability to find your own answers. :)

Comment: I honestly did, and all I came up with is some cryptic info from msdn and stackoverflow. If it means `+=`, then how would it apply to a bool? Also, I posted an answer that implement's your original solution. Can you tell me what you think of it?

Comment: `|` is the OR operator, and `=` is the assignment operator. `A |= B` means "Assign the value of `A OR B` back into `A`". Just like `A += B` means "Assign the value of `A + B` back into `A`"